# Can i get back a formated json response when i do Model.find({}) to find all documents with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to get back a response like this , //JSON res format: [{"_id": data._id, "title": data.title}] . But it returns the whole collection, I can't get back a selective item like only the title from the collection.

My code snippet

```
const bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  comments: []
})

const Books = mongoose.model("Books", bookSchema);
module.exports = function (app) {

  app.route('/api/books')
    .get(function (req, res){
      //response will be array of book objects
      //json res format: [{"_id": bookid, "title": book_title, "commentcount": num_of_comments },...]
    Books.find({}, (err, data) => {
      res.json(data.title)
    })
    })
  
    .post(function (req, res){
      var title = req.body.title;
      //response will contain new book object including atleast _id and title
    const newBookTitle = new Books({
      title
    })
    newBookTitle.save(function(err, booksData) {
      if(err) return res.json(err)
      res.json(booksData)
    })
    })
```

data.title returns null value?

Answer (score 0):

`Model.Find()` returns a Mongoose Query object. You would also need to do a **query.Exec()** to execute the query.

See the documentation [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html)

**Querying**:
Finding documents is easy with Mongoose, which supports the rich query syntax of MongoDB. Documents can be retrieved using each model `find`, `findById`,`findOne`, or where static methods.

```
Tank.find({ size: 'small' })
.where('createdDate').gt(oneYearAgo)
.exec(callback);
```

See the chapter on [queries](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) for more details on how to use the [Query](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query-js) API.

Comment: Found a simple solution of what i wants to return. Iterate the JSON and push all the titles to a new array/object that I can then return.   _let arr = [];
    
    Books.find({}, (err, data) => {
    data.map(item => {
      arr.push(item.title)
    })
      return res.json(arr)
  })_